# Mastering CI infrastructure changes with GitLab

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, gitlab

With Bamboo, a best practice for infrastructure management of agents seems to be using Docker: any time you need a new version of compiler or test tool, the path to deploy a modified version of an agent is very fast.

How could this work with GitLab?

Comment: This topic seems well documented on gitlab website: https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html

Answer (score 3):

Gitlab CI supports running all of your builds inside Docker containers so you have a clean build environment every time. I'd recommend starting with the basic [Docker executor](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/docker.html) but there is also an opportunity to [autoscale your runners](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/autoscaling.html) using [Docker Machine](https://docs.docker.com/machine/) or to [execute the runners on a Kubernetes pod](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/kubernetes.html).

If you need to use Docker as part of your build (such as building, tagging and pushing images) then you can either use [Docker in Docker](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html#use-docker-in-docker-executor) or, preferably, [bind mount the Docker socket](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html#use-docker-socket-binding) of the host into your runner allowing it to run Docker containers as a sibling rather than child process. Note that the [original author of DIND](https://jpetazzo.github.io/) [recommends](https://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/09/03/do-not-use-docker-in-docker-for-ci/) using bind mounting instead of DIND, especially for CI.

To bind mount the Docker socket register your runner with the following command:

```
sudo gitlab-runner register -n \
  --url https://gitlab.com/ \
  --registration-token REGISTRATION_TOKEN \
  --executor docker \
  --description "My Docker Runner" \
  --docker-image "docker:latest" \
  --docker-volumes /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

And then in your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file you can define your job as so:

```
image: docker:latest

before_script:
- docker info

build:
  stage: build
  script:
  - docker build -t my-docker-image .
  - docker run my-docker-image /script/to/run/tests
```

Using just the basic `docker` image rather than the `docker:dind` image

Answer (score 1):

I prefer [DIND](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html) as every run start with a clean sheet. Otherwise the docker image will be built on the gitlab host itself.

- installation of gitlab runner
- registration of runner

> ```
> sudo gitlab-ci-multi-runner register -n \
>   --url https://gitlab.com/ \
>   --registration-token REGISTRATION_TOKEN \
>   --executor docker \
>   --description "My Docker Runner" \
>   --docker-image "docker:latest" \
>   --docker-privileged
> ```

- commit and push .gitlab-ci.yml

> ```
> image: docker:latest
>
> # When using dind, it's wise to use the overlayfs driver for
> # improved performance.
> variables:
>   DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
>
> services:
> - docker:dind
>
> before_script:
> - docker info
>
> build:
>   stage: build
>   script:
>   - docker build -t my-docker-image .
>   - docker run my-docker-image /script/to/run/tests
> ```